# Как отфильтровать определенные div с классами, совпадающие с дата-атрибутами ссылки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть фильтр, который при клике на кнопку должен отображать `div` с классом с  соответствующим ему пунктом **get-age**,

т.е. по клику на ссылку с `get-age="age_3_6"` должен остаться только `div` с классом `age_3_6` и т.п. Кнопка *все* должна выводить все div как и сейчас,

если нет совпадающих дата-атрибутов и классов - ничего не выводить. У меня почему-то не получается это сделать - где-то ошибка - [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/m3nzok5d/)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#section-method a.get-age', function() {
  $('#section-method .ped').show();
  $('#section-method a.get-age').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('#section-method .ped').not($(this).attr('get-age')).hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '#section-method a.get-age-all', function() {
  if ($('#section-method a.get-age').hasClass('active')) {
    $('#section-method a.get-age').removeClass('active');
  }
  $('#section-method .ped').show();
});
```

```css
.ages {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section-method">
  <div class="ages">
    <a href="javascript:;" get-age="age_3_6" class="get-age">до 6</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" get-age="age_7_10" class="get-age">7-10</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" get-age="age_11_16" class="get-age">11-16</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="get-age-all">Все</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ped_holder">
    <div class="ped age_7_10">от 7 до 10</div>
    <div class="ped age_3_6">от 3 до 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что сюда передаётся строка age_3_6, к селектор класса .age_3_6

```
$('#section-method .ped').not($(this).attr('get-age')).hide();
```

Если добавить точку чтобы получился селектор класса, то всё заработает

```
$('#section-method .ped').not('.'+$(this).attr('get-age')).hide();
```